# JSON Errors + Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, sbjson, nsjsonserialization

I have found a few ways to parse `JSON` in `Objective-C`:

- [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)
- [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Both of these methods work great, however my only problem is that when an error occurs, I would like more details than the error message. Specifically, I would like to know the line number and column that the error occurs on (both SBJSON and NSJSONSerialization do return errors, however the errors seem to only contain a Message with no more details).

Any suggestions on how I can get more details on the error that occurs when processing `JSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when receiving an error from `NSJsonSerialization`, I am able to get more details about the error with the following code:

```
NSString * details = [[error userInfo] objectForKey: @"NSDebugDescription"];
```

Which gives me the character index of where the error happens. From this I was able to figure out the line.